# PHP-EWS SOAP client returned status of 401

Tags: php, exchange-server, php-ews

I am using [PHP-EWS](https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews) library(new version) to display the calendar events of the users in my project.
When enabling Extended Protection,
authentication fails. Is there a solution to this?
Thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFZ08.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Same issue here... 401 since Extended Protection was enabled. I'm using garethp's fork of PHP-EWS.

Answer (score 0):

It's been logged as an issue on GitHub:
https://github.com/Garethp/php-ews/issues/261

Although there is not any movement on it yet so no solution yet I'm afraid but, it would be worth watching.